# How to make an index.html that dynamically redirects to another file depending on browser language or IP address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first stack**overflow** post so please be patient with me :) I am new to web developing and made a complete website with different version of the website in Dutch, German, Italian, and English. Instead of linking them together with a dropdown icon display of the flags like everyone does, I wanted to **dynamically** redirect the visitor to the version of my website that matches his or her browser **language setting** or **IP address**. The reason I want to do this is because the website I am making is for a small Italian business that sells olive oil and their whole label kind of plays on nationalism so this would definitely help bring them costumers.

[What I mean with "a dropdown icon display of the flags"](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/15641/screenshots/696122/language_dropdown.png)

So effectively, I want a visitor to open my website, then the website recognizes their **browser language** or **physical location** and redirects them based on that to a new index.html with their language so they would never have to know that the company is a multinational selling company.

I am too noob to get this to work, I tried to fiddle around with javascript but I had no success.

Thanks for any replies in advance... Any help at all is appreciated.

Kind regards, Liam :)

Comment: You can use `navigator.language`

Comment: Don't make it an "one solution only" thing. With your approach I would get the german content but there are often times really bad translations (e.g. Microsoft/MSDN) out there and I would prefer to read the "native" version if possible. Or what if I'm using a public computer/WiFi/VPN in France?

Comment: You *have* to give the user a way to choose a language, because you may select the wrong one for them.  Not everyone in the UK would want to see an English version of a website (for example).  You definitely will drive away some users if they don't have the option to change the language manually.  So while you *can* do what you're asking, you should really do both.  Get the dropdown working first and then look to implement some sort of *"Would you prefer to see this site in German?"* type dialog afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

check `window.navigator.language`

You can get the IP address using the webrtc protocol